# Is the Arcane Archer's feature "Banishing Arrow" redundant for a Curse of Strahd character?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, planes, curse-of-strahd, arcane-archer

My understanding is that, per the "Alterations the Magic" section in Curse of Strahd: -

> spells cast for the purpose of leaving Barovia simply fail, as do effects that banish a creature to another plane of existence.

Given that the Arcane Archer's Banishing Arrow feature states that it

> banish[es] your target to a harmless location in the Feywild.

am I right in understanding that it simply has no effect while the character is in Barovia (and therefore might be a bad pick for a potential player to choose)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### You are right

The Feywild is another plane of existence (see the DMG p. 49). The arrow causes an effect that would **banish a creature to another plane of existence**. Hence it would not work, and would be a bad choice for a player to pick for their character in a campaign playing in Barovia.

The full text of the restriction states:

> No spell-not even *wish*-allows one to escape
> from Strahd's domain. *Astral projection, teleport, plane
> shift*, and similar spells cast for the purpose of leaving
> Barovia simply fail, as do effects that banish a creature
> to another plane of existence. These restrictions apply
> to magic items and artifacts that have properties that
> transport or banish creatures to other planes.

The effect is extremely powerful. There should be no exceptions if not even *wish* can create any.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but it does feel kind of silly to prevent *temporary* banishment spells from working (note that all the spells explicitly mentioned are potentially permanent, and "banish" often means permanent as well, even if they confused matters by providing temporary banishing effects that make no sense at all). As a DM, I'd be willing to simply substitute the effect with one that briefly removes them from existence, sends them to a harmless location in some other domain of dread, etc.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, that seems reasonable. Other extradimensional effects are not banned, e.g. you can have a portable hole or mordenkainen’s mansion. You could redefine it to go to one of those, instead of the Feywild.

Comment: I wondered about that. I might fluff something up, if my player picks that effect.

Comment: @DanO'Shea I would discuss it with your player before they pick, because 'no banishment' is a spoiler that a lot of people already know, so they may want to pick it, but just not because they don't think it will be allowed. If you are going to consider it, let them know.

Comment: Part of the fun and appeal of Ravenloft at least in the "old days" was that the players had to discover these limitations, not meta-game their PC creation to avoid them with prior knowledge. Saddens me how settings have changed so that everyone has there cake and gets to eat it too.

Comment: @Slagmoth Making a permanent character development choice and then discovering that what you picked is completely useless in the campaign you are playing is a really frustrating moment.

Comment: @Philipp Agreed. But Ravenloft wasn't about making things easy for the players, which is why that campaign setting was only popular with a few. Most of the Ravenloft modules started off with PCs from other planes ending up in Ravenloft and the horror of the entity changing things they were used too, etc etc. I was just stating I was sad at how watered down the game has become is all. Do what's right for your table of course but it sort of takes the punch out of system when you tell them all the things before they happen.

Comment: @Slagmoth I think a lot has changed between editions in the way that the game is approached. It was more adversarial back in the day, and far more co-operative these days. It is a huge part in why D&D is more popular than ever, but I do see the appeal of not knowing and sometimes my meta knowledge is quite a burden as a payer.

Comment: @SeriousBri I mean it could be done without being adversarial. I had to do something similar in my homebrew world when my players made characters. I told the players that were making certain choices that there may be consequences to that choice... I just didn't tell them what that consequence was. And yes the editions have changed a bit but it was only adversarial if your table was adversarial and PC death was far more common. Actions had consequence which more people could learn is not a bad thing irl. A proper reveal during the story is a very memorable experience is all I am saying.